# Williams R Ta-lib getting TypeError with look back period

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, ta-lib

I have a question about ta-lib from [here](https://technical-analysis-library-in-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ta.html):
My code:

```
import pandas as pd
# import matplotlib
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import ta


df = web.DataReader('F', 'yahoo')

williams1 = ta.momentum.WilliamsRIndicator(
        high = df['High'], 
        low = df['Low'], 
        close = df['Close'], 
        fillna = False
        )

williams1.wr()
```

On the website it mentions `look back period`:
[image]

How can one add this parameter? I tried to add `int =14` but get error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'int'
```

If i don't include this the code works but i assume i need to add a number for period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misreading the signature, it's `lbp=14`:

```
williams1 = ta.momentum.WilliamsRIndicator(
    high=df["High"],
    low=df["Low"],
    close=df["Close"],
    lbp=14,
    fillna=False,
)
```